# Problem with ' char in SQLite - Android

Tags: android, sqlite, search

Whenever the search query contains the ' char my android app crashes, because it thinks the ' splits the String.
Here's an example -

```
Cursor selCur= myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM drinks WHERE name like '%"+editTextSearch.getText().toString()+"%'", null);
```

Whenever `editTextSearch.getText().toString()` contains a ' (for example - "Ben's") the app crashes.

I can't think of anyway around it.
Could really use help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you really should do is use the `SQLiteDatabase` method `rawQuery` with a String array for selection args:

`Cursor selCur= myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM drinks WHERE name like ?", new String[] {"%" + editTextSearch.getText().toString() + "%"});`

You place a question mark `?` in place of the string you wish to have there, and put the actual string in an array, like i have above.  You can have multiple `?` in your query string, just make sure your array size matches how many `?` you have.

Edit: also for using `like`, you may want to add the `%` symbol inside the String array like i have just changed.  I found that this results in a query that i expect rather than including the `%` in the query string itself.

Answer (score 0):

escape the ' character, not sure if this is the correct syntax but something like this should work:

```
Cursor selCur= myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM drinks WHERE name like '%"+editTextSearch.getText().toString().replace("'", "''")+"%'", null);
```

Beware of sql injection by the way. you should validate editTextSearch field for sql injection.

Answer (score 0):

You should use it this way:

String args[] = new String[]{editTextSearch.getText().toString()};

Cursor selCur= myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM drinks WHERE name like '%?%'", args);